# What Kind Of Keto-friendly Office Treat Can I Bring In Since Pastries Are Not An Option?

Tags: gifts, food

I'm working for a new team today, and occasionally as a show of good will I like to bring in some donuts for the team to enjoy.

On my new team however, there is one person who is on a strict Keto diet for their diabetes - I do not want to exclude this person, but I would still like to bring something in that everyone can enjoy in the office.

What could I bring in that everyone in the office could enjoy?

Comment: Remember that just because one person can't eat donuts that doesn't mean you can't bring them in. Bringing in donuts AND a keto-friendly option should be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Isn't there also a [good place on SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) to get help with food & stuff?

Comment: Too broad a question. There is almost nothing that _someonne_ isn't allergic to, or dislikes, or that is forbidden on their diet either right now or permanently. Ask the people involved, not the Internet. And be prepared for the possibility that there is no way to delight everyone, and that's OK as long as you've made a reasonable attempt.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 the coworker is on a keto diet, which means very few carbs at all, not just no sugar.

Comment: @keshlam It's a very narrow question. People are just overthinking it. He's asking very specifically about keto-friendly. Presumably he has already worked out that the rest of the employees have no special restrictions. e.g. people bringing up allergies are answering a question that wasn't being asked.

Comment: VTC - this essentially is a food/cooking question, not a Workplace question. You've already decided you want to show up with food on your first day - which is a great way to start your work relationship - you just want **dietary** options so everyone can enjoy.

Comment: @JamieB: OK, if you're sure that's the focus, changing headline. It's still likely to be deemed offtopic, but...

Comment: @TheDemonLord: Disagree. It is about food in the workplace, not about food preparation.

Comment: @Flater Yeah, not sure I'd ask cooking SE about what take-out food is good to bring to the workplace. Seems more.....workplace related. Also not opinion based, since "what are some good keto friendly snacks to bring in to work" is actually not that easy to answer (take-out snacks are overwhelmingly *not* keto friendly).

Comment: "What are good keto friendly snacks" is Food. "What are good snacks to bring to the office" depends on the specific office and people in it, and is probably unanswerable as posed. "What are bad snacks for the office" might be answerable: anything particularly likely to make a mess, to trigger allergies by mere proximity, or to be deliberately insensitive. The best bet is to ask locally, not on the Internet.

Answer (score 9):

> On my new team however, there is one person who is on a strict Keto diet for their diabetes - I do not want to exclude this person, but I would still like to bring something in that everyone can enjoy in the office.

The team member with the dietary restriction is going to be much better placed to answer what they would like then we are - so ask *them*. You don't have to get a one-size fits all (and it would likely be a fool's errand to try), you can get pastries for the team and get the keto-coworker something for them.

> Hey Bob, I was planning on bringing some treats in for the team, my normal go-to is pastry but I guess that wouldn't work with your diet and I don't want you to feel left out. What I can I get you that you'd like?

Comment: Even further— don't "guess" what would or wouldn't work. Presupposing that they can't participate in the same activity as everyone else is explicitly exclusive. I would suggest something like "I thought that mightn't work." And don't assume they want anything either. I'd ask "Is there anything I can get you?" not "What can I get you?" You don't know, they might be okay with having a pastry just once, or they might not be able to have anything at all (if for example they also have to limit when they eat).

Answer (score 5):

Employee snacks can be a surprisingly contentious topic! It's hard to please everyone, and the more people there are, the more impossible this becomes, but in terms of keto, you have some fairly easy options:

[Charcuterie boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcuterie_board). Often you can find these at grocery stores, ready made. Sometimes they have non-keto friendly items in them (jellies, crackers) but as someone who does keto I'd be happy to let my coworkers handle the crackers and jellies and I'll stick with the meats and cheeses.

More breakfasty: crustless [quiche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiche). Quiches are almost always keto-friendly, with the crust being the problem. Keto (or low carb dieting in general) is fairly popular these days so you can likely find some crustless quiche options around you.

There are plenty of other ideas out there for keto snacks (I also like pork rinds with a creamy brie dip, or whole milk greek yogurt and blackberries) but the charcuterie board seems like a best bet (if you have people doing keto *and* people on vegan diets then we'll have to call in some experts and make Venn diagrams.)

Be wary of fruits, veggies, and dips unless you want to spend time scrutinizing them. Half of doing keto is snacking on something, reading the label halfway through and going "Oh" because you thought it was low carb but actually was not.

Comment: There's what seems to be a [good alternative](https://www.eatingwell.com/recipe/259080/strawberry-chocolate-greek-yogurt-bark/)

Comment: @OldPadawan Yeah, loads of options if they're willing to cook. But I'm thinking more "donut substitute" as in something that's simple to grab off a shelf, or order for pickup, and take into work.

Comment: Yeah, but almost *nothing* will be a one-size-fits-all treat. So OP's best bet might 15mns of homework or a specialized shop IMO

Comment: A cheese board is probably safer than charcuterie given some people don't eat pork and some people don't eat any meat. But if it's a mix of cheese and meats, that could work too.

Comment: @KateGregory and many people are lactose intolerant or allergic to dairy...

Comment: All true! However, OP was asking specifically about keto. He was not asking about vegan, kosher, hallal, nut allergies, etc. I'll assume he's worked the rest out and his one known stipulation is "keto friendly".

Answer (score -1):

Something famous in your region if you are an immigrant, I would love something new and exciting to be offered as a treat.
If not go with the second popular treat of the country you are residing in.

Answer (score -2):

Some mixed fruits?  Apples, bananas, oranges, etc.
Bagels?  Might still be an issue for a diabetic.
A "combo" of donuts, bagels, fruits?

There are many possibilities.

Comment: This answer might not be your best bet though... "*According to the [USDA](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/1105314/nutrients), one banana has more than 20g net carbs, you may blow your entire allowance on a single one.*". [Several fruits are high in sugar and carbs. Your best bet is to reach for blackberries, blueberries, raspberries, strawberries, and tomatoes](https://www.atkins.com/how-it-works/library/articles/helpful-tips-ketogenic-foods-to-avoid). Here are [some sweets](https://www.eatingwell.com/recipes/18355/health-condition/diabetic/desserts/)